# Table alias lost when using joins with SqlExpressionSelectFilter

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a situation where records should be excluded depending on a value in a related table. When using joins with SqlExpressionSelectFilter the generated SQL will not use table alias for part of the query. I am running ServiceStack 5.5.

```
OrmLiteConfig.SqlExpressionSelectFilter = q => {
    if (q.ModelDef.ModelType.HasInterface(typeof(IJoinFilter))) {
        q.LeftJoin<IJoinFilter, FirstTable>((f, j) => f.FirstTableId == j.Id)
             .Where<FirstTable>(j => j.Deleted != true);
    }
};
```

And simply selecting from it with:

```
db.Select(db.From<SecondTable>().Where<SecondTable>(x => x.Id == 1));
```

This generates something like:

```
SELECT SecondTable.Id, SecondTable.FirstTableId, SecondTable.Deleted 
FROM SecondTable 
LEFT JOIN FirstTable ON (SecondTable.FirstTableId = FirstTable.Id)
WHERE (Id = 1) AND (FirstTable.Deleted <> 1)
```

Notice the Id in the where clause is not prepended with 'SecondTable'. There are also cases for which the select clause will not include aliases.

Are joins in select filters supported? Is there a recommended way I should be doing this kind of global filter instead?

I've created a quick repro here: https://github.com/TheScobey/OrmliteSelectFilterIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SqlExpressionSelectFilter` is applied after the expression is created so wont be able to impact previous expressions, you can try giving the Source From table an alias with:

```
db.Select(db.From<SecondTable>(db.TableAlias(nameof(SecondTable)))
    .Where<SecondTable>(x => x.Id == 1));
```

An alternative is to force the query to include the table prefix in queries, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<SecondTable>();
q.PrefixFieldWithTableName = true;
q.Where<SecondTable>(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the query ended up using the custom alias in the base expression, but the default alias for the join:

    SELECT st.Id, st.FirstTableId, st.Deleted 
    FROM SecondTable st 
    LEFT JOIN FirstTable ON (SecondTable.FirstTableId = FirstTable.Id)
    WHERE (st.Id = @0) AND (FirstTable.Deleted <> @1)

Comment: @Will It doesn't have the concrete type in the SelectFilter to be able to know which table alias it can use, you can use the same name as the table for the alias, e.g. [here's a live example on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=9b4ec6a4808ad6271bf4cfdacbf6ffd2&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a).

Comment: Can PrefixFieldWithTableName be applied to all queries for a particular table?

Comment: @Will Easiest way would be to wrap it in your own ext method (e.g. `FromTable<T>`) that initializes the query with your preference. I've just added additional global config options that you can do this with `OrmLiteConfig.IncludeTablePrefixes = true` and `OrmLiteConfig.SqlExpressionInitFilter = q => q.PrefixFieldWithTableName = true`. This change is available from the latest v5.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).